# How to write a Traversable instance for function, in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, traversable

How do I write the *Traversable* instance for `((->) a)`?

I think I could do it, *if* I could generically unwrap an *Applicative Functor*:

```
instance Traversable ((->) k) where
  -- traverse :: (a -> f b) -> (k -> a) -> f (k -> b)
  -- traverse h t = ?
  -- h                     :: Applicative f => a -> f b
  -- t                     :: k -> a
  -- h . t                 :: k -> f b
  -- unwrap . h . t        :: k -> b
  -- pure $ unwrap . h . t :: f (k -> b)
  traverse h t = pure $ unwrap . h . t

unwrap :: (Functor f, Applicative f) => f a -> a
unwrap y@(pure x) = x
```

But, alas, GHC won't let me get away with that:

```
Parse error in pattern: pure
```

Comment: First you would need to create an instance of `Foldable`.

Comment: `pure` is a function, not a data constructor. The closest thing to a constructor for a function value is a lambda expression: `\x -> x + 1 :: Num a => (-> a) a`. What value of type `Num a => a` do you imagine you could extract from this function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally there is no such thing as `unwrap`, consider `f` being the list functor `[]` what should `unwrap` return for `[_, _, _]` or better yet for the empty list `[]`? Similar thing with `Maybe`, suppose `h` is `const Nothing`, you would expect to get `Nothing`. But your line of thought would fail upon trying to `unwrap` the `Nothing` into a value `a`. You can notice that trying to apply `pure` (to re-pack the result in the functor) means that you expect the result to be always `Just` for `Maybe` functor, non-empty for `[]` etc.

There is little hope for `Traversable` instance for a reader functor `((->) k)`. While it is not proof, a good evidence in that direction is that such an instance is missing from the `Prelude`. Also to traverse a function and produce a final container (`[]` or `Maybe`) you would need to apply your function `h` to any thinkable output of the function, that is a lot of potential values, in general infinitely many.

```
Prelude> traverse (\n -> if n == 42 then Nothing else Just n) [1, 2, 3]
Just [1,2,3]
Prelude> traverse (\n -> if n == 42 then Nothing else Just n) [1..]
Nothing
```

suppose that `k` is `Int`, so the functor is `Int ->`, suppose you have a value `g :: Int -> Int`, let it be `\n -> if n == 42 then 0 else n`, suppose you wanted to traverse that value with the above function, that traversal would be `Nothing` if `g` outputs `42` for any input, but it doesn't. The traversal cannot know that though (it has no access to the code of the function), so it would have to try all outputs.

If `k` were finite, then you could traverse a function by tabulating it. After traversing the table you could possibly produce a result. This may not be what you are after but:

```
import Data.Char
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Word

instance ( Enum k, Bounded k ) => Foldable ((->) k) where
    foldMap h f = foldMap (h . f) domain

instance ( Enum k, Bounded k, Eq k ) => Traversable ((->) k) where
    traverse h f = fmap (\vs k -> fromJust $ k `lookup` zip domain vs) (traverse (h . f) domain)

domain :: ( Enum k, Bounded k ) => [k]
domain = enumFromTo minBound maxBound

tabulate :: ( Enum k, Bounded k ) => (k -> a) -> [(k, a)]
tabulate f = zip domain (map f domain)

f1 :: Bool -> Int
f1 b = if b then 42 else 666

f2 :: Ordering -> Char
f2 LT = 'l'
f2 EQ = 'e'
f2 GT = 'g'

f3 :: Word8 -> Bool
f3 n = fromIntegral n < 256

f4 :: Word16 -> Bool
f4 n = fromIntegral n < 256

main = do
    print (tabulate f1)
    print (tabulate <$> traverse (\n -> [n, 2*n]) f1)
    putStrLn ""
    print (tabulate f2)
    print (tabulate <$> traverse (\c -> [c, toUpper c]) f2)
    putStrLn ""
    print (tabulate f3)
    print (tabulate <$> traverse (\b -> if b then Just b else Nothing) f3)
    putStrLn ""
    print (tabulate <$> traverse (\b -> if b then Just b else Nothing) f4)
```

Answer (score 1):

> But, alas, GHC won't let me get away with that:

It seems your error is that you tried to use a function (`pure`) as a pattern. Haskell only allows *constructors* to appear in patterns. So

```
unwrap (Just x) = x
```

is valid, while

```
unwrap (pure x) = x
```

is not.