# Can `A => List[B]` be transformed into a `List[A => B]`?

Tags: scala, function, types, functional-programming, function-composition

I am trying to find an implementation for this Scala function signature:

```scala
def explode[A, B](f: A => List[B]): List[A => B]
```

The opposite direction is possible:

```scala
def nest[A, B](fs: List[A => B]): A => List[B] = (a: A) => fs.map(_(a))
```

By now I am tending to believe the first one (`explode`) is unimplementable, but I am happy to be proven wrong. If it is indeed not possible to implement, is there a deep reasoning behind it?

In my view, I am essentially asking the compiler to "duplicate" that input `A` some `n` times (the `List`s size), and "fix" it as input.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65454714/can-a-listb-be-transformed-into-a-lista-b?noredirect=1#comment115732285_65455305).
(Also, they're not all the same function, each yields a different `B`)

Comment: Yes, sorry. I still think it would be worth to explain what you want to do

Comment: Why don't you work with lists of tuples? Or Maps? Something like that: `def explode[A, B](f: A => List[B])(a: A): List[(A, B)] = {
  f(a).map(b => a -> b)
}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my view, I am essentially asking the compiler to "duplicate" that input `A` some `n` times (the `List`s size), and "fix" it as input.

The problem is you don't know what `n` is. Consider for example a function that returns a list of all the prime divisors of a number:

```
def divisors(n: Int): List[Int] = ???
```

What do you expect `explode(divisors)` to be? `divisors` can return a `List` of any size, depending on its argument, whenever it's invoked in the future. But when you call `explode` it has to return a `List` of a fixed size immediately.

Given a fixed type `A`, the signatures in your code can be written like this:

```
type F[T] = List[T]
type G[T] = A => T

def nest[B]: F[G[B]] => G[F[B]]
def explode[B]: G[F[B]] => F[G[B]]
```

`nest` and `explode` are reminiscent to [`sequence`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/applicative.html#traverse) operation. It works for `nest`, because it's possible to write a [`Traverse`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/traverse.html) instance for a `List`, but it's not possible to write a `Traverse` instance for a function `A => T`. Here is an equivallent [question for Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332201/how-to-write-a-traversable-instance-for-function-in-haskell), that gives some more insight.

Comment: Thank you for your informative response! You write: "...But when you call `nest` it has to return a List of a fixed size immediately." (I believe you meant `explode`).
And that is true. I am trying to think if the answer could be different if I was willing to give up the part where the list returns with a fixed size immediately - what if I was to work with `Stream` / `LazyList` etc.?

Comment: I think, `Stream` is still not good, because it's possible to exhaust it immediately immediately, e.g. `explode(divisors).toList`. And the `List` may have to be empty for some `n`. Is it a theoretical question, or do you have some problem you want to solve?

Comment: I see what you mean. I think empty `List` can work out fine though, but the essence remains in tact.
This is mostly theoretical but it stems from a side project I am trying out. I am afraid giving out more detailed context would be too complicated and won't help out. Essentially this means I probably should look up another direction in modeling my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make some implementation that just satisfies the signature you can do something like this:

```
def explode[A, B](f: A => List[B]): List[A => B] = {
  Nil
}

def explode[A, B](f: A => List[B]): List[A => B] = {
  List(f.andThen(_.head))
}
```

But I guess you want something semantically different:

> "duplicate" that input A some n times (the Lists size), and "fix" it
> as input

In that case, there is a problem. The result of `f`, in the general case, depends on the input `A`. It could be Nil, finite-size list, or infinite list.

What you can do is only something like:

```
def explode[A, B](f: A => List[B]): A => List[A => B] = {
  f.andThen(_.map(b => (_: A) => b)
}
```